# Connect DB with IP address

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to connect my DB through excel macro. the below VBA code I tried but I'm unable to connect to the DB.please assist me.

- DB name: abcd
- Username: praveen
- password: XYZ
- host:10.161.0.XX
- port: 1519
- service name:PRODUCTDB

--------VBA code--------------------------

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rec As ADODB.Recordset
Set con = New ADODB.Connection`enter code here`
Set rec = New ADODB.Recordset
rec.CursorLocation = adUseClient
con.Open ("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=10.161.0.00;port=1519;Service name=PRODUCTDB;Initial Catalog=abcd;user ID=praveen; password=XYZ;")
```

Comment: `Data Source=10.161.0.00,1519;` there's no separate parameter for port.  https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/

Comment: RDBMS is SQL Server ?

Comment: _unable to connect_ Please post the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use something like this to generate the connection string

```
Function ConnStr()
' For this to work we need a reference to
' Microsoft OLE DB Service Component 1.0 Type Library
  '--------------
  'Define variables and objects
  '--------------
  Dim DataLink As DataLinks
  '--------------
  'Create Objects
  '--------------
  Set DataLink = New DataLinks
'display the UDL dialog and put result in the cell
  ConnStr = DataLink.PromptNew()
End Function
```

Comment: I'm sorry, not getting this

Comment: that code will create a function called ConnStr, in your worksheet in any cell type in the formula =ConnStr() a dialog will then appear fill in the details of your server and test once you are happy click ok, the cell will then hold your connection string that you can copy and paste into your code